# Hide button based on PHP result

Tags: php, css

This is what i am trying to achieve but i am not sure how:

- I would like to check if a specific post is published or not
- If it' not published, it should hide a specific button and show a different one in it's place

I think it's a combination of PHP and CSS but i'm not really sure where to start.

Thank you in advance for your help
Charis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_post_status(ID)` to check to see if the post is published. You'll need to pull the post ID (through WP Query/loop/etc)

```
if (get_post_status( $ID ) == "publish"){
    #Show Published Button
} else {
    #Show Not Published Button
}
```

[Get Post Status in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it pointed me to the right direction!